# Adding `Type = SecuritySchemeType.OpenIdConnect` causes swagger to try to load `swagger/undefined`

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, openid-connect, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Using Visual Studio 2022 (17.0.2), I created a Web API Core application, selecting Microsoft Identity as the identity provider.  That template will add in swagger, but it does not set up swagger's security.

I have been trying to get that working and I have narrowed down my problem to the addition of the setting to use OIDC.

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {

        // If this line is commented out, then the error does not occur
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.OpenIdConnect,
        //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


        Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
        {
            AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
            {
                AuthorizationUrl = new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"),
                TokenUrl = new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token"),
                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "openid", "Scope to enable OIDC" } }
            }
        }

    });
});
```

(My full [Program.cs](https://gist.github.com/Vaccano/5970963a66e4450cf10add1053292e9c) is posted here.)

When the line indicated in the comment above is removed, then the swagger page loads just fine (though it does not use OIDC, which I need).

When that line is in the code, then when I load the swagger page, I get this error:

[image: undefined url]

It is odd because the URL it is trying to load is `https://localhost:7019/swagger/undefined`.  Having the word `undefined` as part of the URL is confusing to me.  And why is it only happening when I enable OIDC?

**How can I get this to load correctly with OIDC enabled?**

Comment: did you set the xml document file name and path in the project properties under build?

Comment: @micahkimel -  I am not sure what XML document you are referring to....  I don't have any xml documents in this project (it is just the default template for WebAPI Core).

Comment: Swagger makes a xml file when it builds, but it has to be set up in the project properties under build to have a path or else it won't know where to put it.

Comment: @micahkimel - As I said in the question, the code works fine if I don't put in the line about `OpenIdConnect`.  And I am not doing anything with an XML file.  I am guessing that it must be handled by the Swashbuckle NuGet used by the default Template for WebAPI Core.

Comment: `SecuritySchemeType.OpenIdConnect` requires `OpenIdConnectUrl`, it doesn't use `Flows` (it reads the flows, scopes, etc. from the provided `OpenIdConnectUrl`). `Flows` are only used by `SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2`. See OIDC config example [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/2072#issue-841753065) and OAuth 2.0 config example [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#add-security-definitions-and-requirements).

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: @Brian - unfortunately, this was almost 2 years ago. I do not recall.  But my guess is, no. I usually come back and post the solution if I figure it out.

Comment: I think there were some issues at that time getting OIDC to work, but I did end up getting it to work with the current frameworks. I had to add the following to the pipeline config:
app.UseSwaggerUI( options => {
        options.OAuthUsePkce();
 });